# Sort files by type in sidebar - SublimeText3

Tags: file, sorting, package, sublimetext3

Is there a package for st3 that enables you to sort the files in the sidebar on type/ extention instead alphabeticly?

Something like the SortTabs package, but then for the sidebar.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SortTabs

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, ST API is not that rich to allow to change the sorting. You can join the others [here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19475-side-bar-api/).